# This JavaScript object creation method code, will not run correctly on my computer, but it works fine in the YouTube video why?

Tags: javascript

[image]

```js
function stud(name, age, studies) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.studies = studies;
}
var student = stud("Craig", 21, "Engineering");
//the var student should be students?? But on the video it is student! And it works?

//This is the video I attempted to learn about JavaScript constructors from.
https: //youtu.be/4vyxVhaQSxo?t=555 //When video loads, pause it and check the code! Is 
  the above variable correct i.e.student ? ?
  //As the next lines refer to students.name etc...?? 

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "the student called " + students.name + " 
whose age is " + students.age + "
is studying " + students.studies;
```

I don't understand how this code states there is an error in my browser (Microsoft Edge, Mozilla Firefox and Opera) when I try to run the code from VScode, but not in the browser used in the tutorial. What am I missing?

Comment: “*there is an error in my browser*” Why haven’t you included the full text of the error in the body of your question?

Comment: `student` is not the same as `students`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `this` you should be using `new`, for example:

```js
function Stud(name, age, studies) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.studies = studies;
}

var student = new Stud("Craig", 21, "Engineering");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  `The student called ${student.name} whose age is ${student.age} is studying ${student.studies}.`;
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: You have modified my code to make it work. That was not what I requested. Sorry if I was not clear. The code that I displayed works in the YouTube video, but does not work in my browser, I was trying to find out why. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @SiO Essentially, I have just added the `new` keyword without which the code would not work anywhere. The `stud` function would just return undefined without it. In the vdeo the scripts use `student.name` not `students.name`. Why have *you* modifed the code?

Comment: @SiO The last script appears to work because the scripts above it have already created the innerHTML on the page. The last script will just throw an error because student is undefined but the console is not shown on the video so you do not see that. No chat room is needed, thank you. It is just a silly error not worth wasting any more time on.